# Is it possible to initialize a structure with a dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift

**Swift-3**

```
 struct Book {
        var title: String
        var description: String
        var price: Float
    }
```

I have Book structure which I want to initialize from dictionary

```
var book: Book? = ["Title": "Harry Poter", "Description": "Fantasy Novel", "Price": 190]
```

Is it possible to do in Swift?

Comment: Yes, it is possible (if you write a suitable `init` method)

Comment: Its not even similar to that question @Larme

Comment: @LorenzoB, In my application I have to call a web-service, parse json and initialize Book object from parsed dictionary. So I am using something like in the init method taking values from dict and passing to Book initializer. But if we can reduce this extra step and directly pass dictionary we can initialize Book.

Comment: Your second code snippet would not compile. It should be something like `var bookDictionary: [String: Any] = ["Title": "Harry Poter", "Description": "Fantasy Novel", "Price": 190]`

Comment: Are you using Swift 4?

Comment: @LorenzoB. No. I am using Swift-3

Comment: If using cocoapods is an option, take a look at [Unbox](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Unbox)

Comment: Check [Convenience init](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try to make suitable  init() as Martin says** for your structure and use it according to your requirement:

```
struct Book {
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var price: Int
}

extension Book {
    init(book : Dictionary<String,Any>){
        title = book["Title"] as? String ?? ""
        description = book["Description"] as? String ?? ""
        price = book["Price"] as? Int ?? 0
    }
}

let dict = ["Title": "Harry Poter", "Description": "Fantasy Novel", "Price": 190] as [String : Any]
var book: Book? = Book(book: dict)
print(book!)
```

Comment: This code does not work since the price value always returns `0.0`. The output is `Book(title: "Harry Poter", description: "Fantasy Novel", price: 0.0)`.

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: @LorenzoB when the data comes with value type it works !!